# On the Verification of robin's theorem.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, numerical-methods, analytic-number-theory

Robin's theorem is well known consequence of RH. It was first proved by ramanujan in 1915,but rigorous proof was given by guy robin. It has to do something with divisor function.

"Divisor function - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Coming to my question, I want to know until which number is this verified. Since no counter example is found until now, upto which number they found it to be true?

[image]

Comment: Hope I made my question clear

Comment: Can you also state Robin's theorem in the post?

Comment: I have edited the question placing the theorem

Comment: You might enjoy https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias//doc/elementaryrh.pdf in which Lagarias deduces an even more elementary-looking equivalent of RH from Robin's theorem.  For $n>1$ RH is true iff $$\sigma(n)<H_n+e^{H_n}\log H_n$$  where $H_n$ is the $n$th harmonic number. 
 At the end of section $2$, on page $6$ he says, "One can prove unconditionally that the inequality holds for nearly all integers. ... if there exists any counterexample, the value of $n$ will be very large."   No further details are given. (continued)

Comment: (continuation) I would like to know how "nearly all" is defined in this instance, and any quantification on "very large".

Comment: I have tried this for many numbers using Wolfram alpha and found no counterexamples. I went upto 10^200 but found nothing. So i think "very large" explains the fact that if a counterexample exists it must very large

Comment: I found https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38368568_Robin's_inequality_and_the_Riemann_hypothesis that shows that counterexamples must have asymptotic density $0$.

Comment: @RAHUL Yes, of course, "very large" means "very large."  I mean how large is "very large" in this instance.  If a counterexample exists, then there is a colossally superabundant counterexample (explained in the Lagarias paper) so perhaps you should concentrate you search there.  See [OEIS 4490](http://oeis.org/A004490)